# Wordpress: Rewrite rules custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I created a new custom post type "video" and a new taxonomy "singers". There are 3 singers: Michael Jackson, Madonna, Eminem.

I'd like change the permalink and so I'd like this URL: www.example.com/madonna/video-like-a-prayer (where "madonna" is the singer, "video" is the post type and "like-a-prayer" is the post name).

How can I resolve please? Thanks.

Comment: You could add your own re-write rules and tags to allow you to use a custom permalink structure.  See add_rewrite_rule and add_rewrite_tag.  Also check out this article on how to implement them.  http://www.webtipblog.com/update-url-rewrite-rules-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to do so by having a permanent leading permalink for all video post types so your URL would be:

www.example.com/artist/madonna/video-like-a-prayer

Set your custom post type options to set the permalink_starts_with property.

```
/**
 * Settable options for this plugin.
 *
 * @var mixed[] $options
 */
public  $options                = array(
    'default_comments'                  => '1',
    'default_page_status'               => 'draft',
    'default_trackbacks'                => '1',
    'pages_replace_websites'            => '0',
    'page_template'                     => '',
    'permalink_starts_with'             => 'artist',
    'prevent_new_window'                => '0',
);
```

You can then create your post with titles with an options array like this one:

```
    $this->pageData = array(
        'ID'            => '',
        'post_type'     => $this->pageType,
        'post_status'   => $this->pageDefaultStatus,
        'post_title'    => $this->artist.'-'.$this->video-title,
        'post_content'  => '',
        'slp_notes'     => 'new page'
    );
```

The permalink would then read www.example.com/artist//.

There are other ways to create permalink structures for each artists but I've not found a simple and elegant solution that does not require getting in deep on the rewrite rules and permalink stacks in WordPress.